# SQL Count of rows in a group in a sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I apologise for the title of the question, it isn't very clear, but I can't think of a better way of describing it in words, the data should speak for itself.

I have a table of data where I need to know the count of rows that are the same depending on a value, but also taking into account the sequence they are currently in. The table is much larger than this, but these are the columns which are relevant.

```
Id    | MinCode      | MaxCode      | ExpectedResult
----------------------------------------------------
1     | 00001.000001 | 00001.000001 | 2
2     | 00001.000001 | 00001.000002 | 2
3     | 00002.00001a | 00002.00001a | 3
4     | 00002.00001a | 00002.00001b | 3
5     | 00002.00001a | 00002.00001c | 3
6     | 00002.000002 | 00002.000002 | 1
7     | 00002.00003a | 00002.00003a | 2
8     | 00002.00003a | 00002.00003b | 2
9     | 00002.000002 | 00002.000004 | 1
10    | 00003.000001 | 00003.000001 | 1
```

Note: Id is also the order in this example, I just didn't see the point of an extra column with the same data.

I have tried several versions using `COUNT`, `ROW_NUMBER/RANK`, `PARTITION` and `GROUP BY` without getting the ExpectedResult values. The issue is with Ids 6 and 9 as my ExpectedResult value always combines them to produce a 2 which I partially understand as these functions don't take into account the ordering of the data. I believe I'm close, but my T-SQL is pretty rusty these days!

I know I could get this value with processing this data set through a `CURSOR`, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: The MaxCode seems to be unused to produve the result you want

Comment: It is directly, it was used to get the MinCode value, but it's just representative of the rest of the data in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to create a sequence id you can use in a window function to get the count.  You won't be able to do it in one query because window functions can't be combined, but you can pull it off with a subquery or CTE.

To determine the sequence number for a row, you need to count the number of times the group key has changed in the *preceding* rows.  So to determine the changes, create an inner query that checks if the current group key is different from the previous by using the **lag** window function.  Use a **case** statement that results in 1 or 0 depending on if the lagged value is different from the current.  The outer query then just has to **sum** up the values for all rows preceding up to the current.

Once you have the sequence number, you can use a **count** window function to count all the rows with matching numbers.

```
WITH src AS ( -- cte to mimic table.
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
        (1, N'00001.000001', N'00001.000001', 2),
        /* ... test data ... */
        (10, N'00003.000001', N'00003.000001', 1)
    ) [src] ( [Id],[MinCode],[MaxCode],[ExpectedResult] )
)
SELECT src.Id, MinCode, MaxCode, ExpectedResult
    , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY seq.SequenceId) [Result]
FROM src 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT x.Id, SUM(x.IsNew) OVER (ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) [SequenceId]
    FROM (
        SELECT Id, CASE WHEN LAG(MinCode) OVER (ORDER BY Id) <> MinCode THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [IsNew]
        FROM src 
    ) x
) seq ON seq.Id = src.Id
ORDER BY Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another possibility:

```
/* Testing Data */

DECLARE @Data table (
    Id int, MinCode varchar(20), MaxCode varchar(20), ExpectedResult int
);

INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 1 , '00001.000001', '00001.000001', 2 ),
    ( 2 , '00001.000001', '00001.000002', 2 ),
    ( 3 , '00002.00001a', '00002.00001a', 3 ),
    ( 4 , '00002.00001a', '00002.00001b', 3 ),
    ( 5 , '00002.00001a', '00002.00001c', 3 ),
    ( 6 , '00002.000002', '00002.000002', 1 ),
    ( 7 , '00002.00003a', '00002.00003a', 2 ),
    ( 8 , '00002.00003a', '00002.00003b', 2 ),
    ( 9 , '00002.000002', '00002.000004', 1 ),
    ( 10, '00003.000001', '00003.000001', 1 );

/* Get count of MinCode rows that are the same, taking into account their sequence */

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        MinCode,
        CASE WHEN
                LAG ( MinCode, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) = MinCode
                OR
                LEAD ( MinCode, 1 ) OVER ( ORDER BY Id ) = MinCode
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS SeqMatch
    FROM @Data
)
SELECT
    Id, MinCode, MaxCode, ExpectedResult, 
    CASE WHEN MatchCount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE MatchCount END AS DerivedResult
FROM @Data d
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT SUM( SeqMatch ) AS MatchCount FROM cte WHERE cte.MinCode = d.MinCode
) AS x;
```

**Returns**

```
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
| Id |   MinCode    |   MaxCode    | ExpectedResult | DerivedResult |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
|  1 | 00001.000001 | 00001.000001 |              2 |             2 |
|  2 | 00001.000001 | 00001.000002 |              2 |             2 |
|  3 | 00002.00001a | 00002.00001a |              3 |             3 |
|  4 | 00002.00001a | 00002.00001b |              3 |             3 |
|  5 | 00002.00001a | 00002.00001c |              3 |             3 |
|  6 | 00002.000002 | 00002.000002 |              1 |             1 |
|  7 | 00002.00003a | 00002.00003a |              2 |             2 |
|  8 | 00002.00003a | 00002.00003b |              2 |             2 |
|  9 | 00002.000002 | 00002.000004 |              1 |             1 |
| 10 | 00003.000001 | 00003.000001 |              1 |             1 |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Please note that Daniel Gimenez's answer is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want this

```
SELECT count(*) over (partition by MinCode ) as result
FROM test
order BY id
```

Gives

```
create table test (Id  int, MinCode  VARCHAR(30),   MaxCode  VARCHAR(30),   ExpectedResult INT);


INSERT INTO test VALUES (1    , '00001.000001', '00001.000001', 2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2    , '00001.000001', '00001.000002', 2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3    , '00002.00001a', '00002.00001a', 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4    , '00002.00001a', '00002.00001b', 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5    , '00002.00001a', '00002.00001c', 3);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (6    , '00002.000002', '00002.000002', 1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (7    , '00002.00003a', '00002.00003a', 2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (8    , '00002.00003a', '00002.00003b', 2);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (9    , '00002.000002', '00002.000004', 1);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (10   , '00003.000001', '00003.000001', 1);

SELECT Id,MinCode,MaxCode, ExpectedResult AS You,  
       (count(*) over (partition by MinCode )) as Me
FROM test
order BY id


Id  MinCode         MaxCode         You Me
1   00001.000001    00001.000001    2   2
2   00001.000001    00001.000002    2   2
3   00002.00001a    00002.00001a    3   3
4   00002.00001a    00002.00001b    3   3
5   00002.00001a    00002.00001c    3   3
6   00002.000002    00002.000002    1   2
7   00002.00003a    00002.00003a    2   2
8   00002.00003a    00002.00003b    2   2
9   00002.000002    00002.000004    1   2
10  00003.000001    00003.000001    1   1
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made myself clear in my question, what you have wrote there in the `Me` column is what I have managed to get myself, what I want is what is in the `You` (or in the original question `ExpectedValue`) column.

Comment: ok then I really dont understand how you would get the results with the data shown, I see no correlation. As I said in my first comment, the Maxvalue seems to have no purpose and I dont get why you would want different values for rows 6 and 9